# How to bind value from dropdown list in React?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get the value of the id in my dropdown list to post to an API and i'm not entirely sure how to do that.I Any help would be appreciated

I've tried using the onchange with a handleChange function but it doesn't do anything. The react files are below for the form and for posting of the form

```
import React from "react";
import { updateUsers, fetchUsers } from "./actions/appactions";
import FormChange from "./formchange";
var createReactClass = require("create-react-class");
const Update = createReactClass({
  getIntitialState() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState(props);
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchUsers(this.props.match.params.usersId)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        // this.setState({
        //   users: data
        // });
        this.setState(state => {
          state.users = data;
          return state;
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("error", err);
      });
  },
  handleSubmit(data) {
    updateUsers(this.state.users.id, data);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormChange
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          password={this.state.users.password}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
export default Update;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
var createReactClass = require("create-react-class");
const Form2 = createReactClass({
  //setting initial state
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      customerName: this.props.customerName,
      email: this.props.email,
      businessName: this.props.businessName,
      address: this.props.address,
      city: this.props.city,
      lga: this.props.lga,
      url: this.props.url,
      description: this.props.description,
      obj: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOptions();
  },
  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          obj: json
        });
      });
  },
  handleCustomerChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      customerName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleEmailChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleBusinessChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      businessName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleAddressChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      address: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleCityChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      city: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleLgaChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      lga: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleUrlChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      url: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleDescriptionChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleCatChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      obj: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        name="categories_post"
        className="form-horizontal"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <div id="business_post">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="customerName"
            >
              Customer Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.customerName}
                onChange={this.handleCustomerChange}
                id="customerName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="email">
              Email
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                id="email"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="businessName"
            >
              Business Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.businessName}
                onChange={this.handleBusinessChange}
                id="businessName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="address"
            >
              Address
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.address}
                onChange={this.handleAddressChange}
                id="address"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="city">
              City
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.city}
                onChange={this.handleCityChange}
                id="city"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="lga">
              LGA
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.lga}
                onChange={this.handleLgaChange}
                id="lga"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="url">
              URL
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.url}
                onChange={this.handleUrlChange}
                id="url"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="description"
            >
              Description
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.description}
                onChange={this.handleDescriptionChange}
                id="description"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="email">
              categories name
            </label>
            <div className="drop-down">
              <select>
                {this.state.obj.map(obj => {
                  return (
                    <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
                      {obj.categoryName}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button
                type="submit"
                id="categoriesSubmit"
                className="btn btn-default"
              >
                submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button className="btn btn-danger .mt-3">
                <Link to="/business">Home</Link>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

export default Form2;
```

Comment: where's your dropdown?

Comment: I've edited it and added the dropdown. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it

```
//handlecatchange
  handleCatChange() {
    var value = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.categoryId).value;
    this.setState({
      categoryId: parseInt(value)
    });
  },
```

the dropdown list

```
<div className="drop-down">
              {/* <Select value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} options={this.state.obj}></Select> */}
              <select ref="categoryId" onChange={this.handleCatChange}>
                {this.state.obj.map(obj => {
                  return (
                    <option
                      key={obj.id}
                      value={obj.id}
                      onChange={this.handleCatChange}
                    >
                      {obj.categoryName}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Use react-select, It is able to handle id and value elegantly.
Can you give it a try?

`npm install react-select`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
var createReactClass = require("create-react-class");
import Select from 'react-select';

const Form2 = createReactClass({
  //setting initial state
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      customerName: this.props.customerName,
      email: this.props.email,
      businessName: this.props.businessName,
      address: this.props.address,
      city: this.props.city,
      lga: this.props.lga,
      url: this.props.url,
      description: this.props.description,
      obj: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOptions();
  },
  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          obj: json
        });
      });
  },
  handleCustomerChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      customerName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleEmailChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleBusinessChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      businessName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleAddressChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      address: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleCityChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      city: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleLgaChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      lga: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleUrlChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      url: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleDescriptionChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleCatChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      obj: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  },

handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
   // this.setState({ selectedOption }); add it to state
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        name="categories_post"
        className="form-horizontal"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <div id="business_post">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="customerName"
            >
              Customer Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.customerName}
                onChange={this.handleCustomerChange}
                id="customerName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="email">
              Email
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                id="email"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="businessName"
            >
              Business Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.businessName}
                onChange={this.handleBusinessChange}
                id="businessName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="address"
            >
              Address
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.address}
                onChange={this.handleAddressChange}
                id="address"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="city">
              City
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.city}
                onChange={this.handleCityChange}
                id="city"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="lga">
              LGA
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.lga}
                onChange={this.handleLgaChange}
                id="lga"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="url">
              URL
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.url}
                onChange={this.handleUrlChange}
                id="url"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="description"
            >
              Description
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.description}
                onChange={this.handleDescriptionChange}
                id="description"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="email">
              categories name
            </label>
            <div className="drop-down">
                <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={this.state.obj}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button
                type="submit"
                id="categoriesSubmit"
                className="btn btn-default"
              >
                submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button className="btn btn-danger .mt-3">
                <Link to="/business">Home</Link>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

export default Form2;
```

[react-select docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

Comment: when I write the handlechange function it says unexpected token "=". I've created a .babelrc file but nothing seems to work

Comment: @user10043514 problably you have to install [babel preset-stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2/)  `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-stage-2`

Comment: i have my .babelrc file is ```{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "@babel/preset-stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```  but in my handle change i still get "unexpected token". is there a way i can import it into the form to get it to work?

Comment: have you `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-stage-2` and install the plugin?

Comment: you have a way around, insted of arrow function just bind a function on the constructor